How can non-residents apply for rejsegaranti with Nordjyllands Trafikselskab?
When travelling by train in Denmark, a delay on a train operated by Nordjyllands Trafikselskab (NT) caused me to miss my DSB connection and arrive to my final destination (Flensburg, Germany) with a delay of 120 minutes. Therefore, I am entitled to compensation and I should apply for it with NT (despite DSB having sold me the ticket; both DSB and NT agree on this part).
I am stuck at the compensation form on the second page, where I am asked for a CPR-nr:

Image transcription:

Det indtastede CPR-nr. er ikke gyldigt
CPR-nr. *
Angiv CPR-nr. uden mellemrum eller bindestreg

Meaning:

The entered CPR-nummer is not valid.
CPR-number *
Indicate CPR-number without space or hyphen.

Apparently, the CPR number refers to a Danish personal identification number. I don't have a Danish personal identification number (I am not Danish, and I don't live in Denmark). What can I fill here to complete the form and claim my travel compensation, or how can I claim compensation as a non-resident?

These are real, existing words?! ;-)

Send all information in an e-mail to info@ntmail.dk.
Source: I contacted NT customer service by telephone at +4598111111.  I got a phone answering machine that was only in Danish.  I pressed 4 to speak to a human.  The human spoke English and told me to write all the necessary information (everything the form asks for, minus CPR, plus IBAN and SWIFT) in an e-mail and send it to info@ntmail.dk.
Information current as of 2024-06-19.

It seems that when you use the english language version of the Nordjyllands Trafikselskab website on https://www.en.ntrejse.dk/customer-service/travel-guarantee it suggests that you should call them instead of filling out a form.
As a reference in DSB's brochure on their equivalent travel guarantee (https://www.dsb.dk/globalassets/produkter_og_services/pdf/400403414_folder_basis_rejsetidsgaranti_dk_m65_2dk.pdf - in danish) it seems they can handle non-resident customers travel guarantee cases by allowing the CPR number to be substituted with an IBAN and SWIFT number of the customer. DSB warn it may take up to 30 days to have a refund on a foreign bank account.
